# Custom colors in Qt Designer stylesheets

Tags: css, qt, qt-designer

I'm trying to apply a custom color to several parts of a Qt GUI, using Qt designer and the main stylesheet.

One solution would be using this:

```
#MainWindow{ background-color: #334422; }
#first_label{ background-color: #334422; }
#second_label{ background-color: #334422; }
```

But it is not scalable, what if I want to change that color again? So I tried to use this, that I think it'd work with web .css files:

```
.bg_color{ background-color: #334422; }
#MainWindow{ .bg_color }
#first_label{ .bg_color }
#second_label{ .bg_color }
```

But I get an `Invalid stylesheet` message.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with Qt stylesheet syntax.

As explained in this question/answers : [Using variables in qt StyleSheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898399/using-variables-in-qt-stylesheets)
You can parse+replace yourself some strings in the QSS to insert hex-color-values and then apply it again on your application. **But** this is not possible in Qt Designer, only through the code.